# Shuffle Sibling Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I'm a little frustrated over how to shuffle elements (because I have data stored in them, simply changing the text will not suffice). I'm trying to shuffle sibling elements so I should use .before and .after. This is my current code

```
function shuffle() {
    var children = $("#paren").children();
    randIndex = randomFromTo(0, arr.length - 1);

    for(i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        //But obviously I can't retrieve a specific child like this
        $("#parent nth-child("+randIndex+")").before(children.i);
    }
}
function randomFromTo(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem with it? Does it not work?
You didn't state your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the children as array, shuffle it and append them again. Since they are the same references, appending will actually move them.

```
var parent = $('ul');

var children = parent.children().get().sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
});

parent.append(children);
```

https://tinker.io/54968

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of the elements, shuffle the array, then reappend the elements.

```
function shuffle(parent) {
    var container = document.getElementById(parent),
        children = container.children,
        length = children.length, i,
        tmparr = [];
    for( i=0; i<length; i++) tmparr[i] = children[i];
    tmparr.sort(function() {return 0.5-Math.random();});
    for( i=0; i<length; i++) container.appendChild(tmparr[i]);
}
```

Note complete absence of jQuery. I also parametrised your function so you can call it with `shuffle("paren")` instead of having a single-purpose function.